# Can a US permanent resident re-enter the US with an expired Peruvian passport?

Tags: passports, us-residents, peruvian-citizens

I'm a Peruvian citizen with a US permanent residence card (green card). I entered Mexico by car, using my expired passport. Can I travel back to the US by airplane with the passport which expired a year ago? I came to Mexico because my wife is Mexican and has US citizenship.

Comment: Is your permanent residence card a US permanent residence card (also known as a green card)?

Comment: Yes i have a u.s. permanent residence card

Comment: With that card, you do not need a passport to enter the US.  I don't know about Mexico's exit requirements, if any.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need a passport to travel back to the US, but you [will need a valid US Permanent Resident Card (Green Card)](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1191/~/traveling-outside-of-the-u.s.---documents-needed-for-lawful-permanent-residents) with you. If you've been out of the US for more than a year, you'll also need a Reentry Permit or Returning Resident Visa and may want to consult an immigration lawyer for assistance in making your case that you haven't abandoned permanent residency.

However, to fly to the US, you also need to satisfy the airline's requirements for identification. You'll need to confirm that they will allow you to check-in using only a permanent residency card. Otherwise, you'll have to contact the Peruvian Embassy or Consulate in Mexico to get your passport renewed. You could also cross the land border using only your permanent resident card.

Comment: Im planing on staying here in mexico just for a week (since my wife already Bought our ticket)   but  going back on plane with my wife and Daughter, thank you for your help

Comment: Im just really  worry or being denied the entry o get deported to my country of origin

Comment: @Luis as a US permanent resident you cannot be denied entry or deported unless you voluntarily relinquish your permanent resident status or have it removed by a judge.  The latter can happen only after an extended absence or if you do something to trigger the statutory grounds of deportability such as committing certain crimes.

Comment: or if POTUS makes a executive order and you are unlucky to catch its first day.

Comment: @Aganju That depends on whether an illegal act falls under the definition of "can" in use here.